# Push em Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Não estou conseguindo dar um `push` em meu projeto no Bitbucket, toda vez aparece a mensagem abaixo. Eu sigo as instruções colocando o e-mail e nome, mas quando volto a dar os comandos aparece a mesma mensagem de novamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu criei um diretório novo, e utilizo os seguintes comandos:

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https:***********
git push -u origin master
```

Estou usando a ferramenta `git`, baixado [neste site](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

Comment: Sei que não responde sua dúvida, mas vai uma dica. Já deu uma olhada no GitExtensions? É muito completo e tem várias opções na própria interface.

Comment: Você precisa criar a chave SSH, aqui tem o tutorial de como criar e adicionar na conta
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html O endereço do repositório vai ser `git://bitbucket.org/<usuario>/<repositorio>`

Comment: Já existe uma pergunta aberta no stackoverflow para seu problema, com várias respostas. Caso não queira criar uma chave SSH, sugiro olhar esse link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433970/unable-to-auto-detect-email-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433970/unable-to-auto-detect-email-address)

Comment: O print da tela já diz tudo: o git não sabe quem tu é, nem teu nome nem email.
Basta executar os dois comandos que estão escritos

Answer (score 5):

Na verdade é o próprio Git que te está bloqueando, não o Bitbucket, por conta de você não ter usuário e e-mail devidamente configurados, apenas faça:

```
git config --local user.name "Henrique Mendes"
```

Ou o nome que desejar, para configurar seu nome dentro no Git para este repositório (o "--local") e:

```
git config --local user.mail "usuario@email.com.br"
```

Para seu endereço de e-mail. Estas informações são usadas para registrar a autoria dos *commits*.